# Ubuntu OS for Win Vista 32bit

Tags: system-installation

Which Ubuntu OS should I download to change my Win Vista 32bit Os to Ubuntu?
I can only fid Ubuntu Os for 64 bit.

Comment: That depends on your hardware. Having a 32-bit Windows does NOT mean your system is NOT 64-bit. If it is: consider getting a replacement since it will be a system from BEFORE 2004. Systems after that should have some sort of fix: PAE or should be 64bit Beside that: Ubuntu community flavours, for example Lubuntu, will continue to support 32bit software and release iso files for the near future.

Comment: Which processor is built in you computer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it does not provide any kind of hardware specs. What OS you run is irrelevant. Could you please edit the question to provide some minimum information about your hardware? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Answer (score 4):

Check at the [Intel ARK](https://ark.intel.com/) website to determine if your computer's processor supports the 64-bit instruction set. Also your computer should have at least 3GB of RAM for best results running a 64-bit operating system.

If you find that you need to install a 32-bit release, you can download Ubuntu 16.04 32-bit. Ubuntu 16.04 is a Long Term Support (LTS) release which is supported by updates until April, 2021.

Starting with Ubuntu 17.10 there is no longer a 32-bit iso file available to download, only a 64-bit iso file, however 32-bit iso files are still available for the 17.10 releases of Ubuntu MATE, Kubuntu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu, Ubuntu Budgie, Ubuntu Studio and Ubuntu Kylin.

Comment: that's much better @karel

Comment: I would mention flavors that continue to support 32-bit architecture if OP really needs 32-bit OS (like [Rinzwind has mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/questions/996493/ubuntu-os-for-win-vista-32bit#comment1609232_996493) already). A future switch from Ubuntu to e.g. Lubuntu can be avoided by carefully choosing now.